# How to create a search function for products and update the product if it exists or otherwise create it?

Tags: c#, woocommerce

I have this problem where I have to create a function to be able to create a new product for a Woocommerce shop.

When the product is created, the code has to go in and check if the product is previously created and then update it if it's there. If not, it creates the new product.

This is my code:

```
using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce.v3.Extension;

string Warenumber = "test 1";
String Name = "Test 2";
double price = 30.25; 

RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://shop.intradata.dk/wp-json/wc/v3/", "ck_609e267849532f784408090aa0a60011c327d291", "cs_64a053471838f3cfd0810bdaaa0c0279771202ac");
WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

//Get all products
var products = await wc.Product.GetAll();

//create a seatch funtion and create or update product

//Add new product
Product p = new Product()
{
    name = "15",
    description = "test product 8",
    price = 8.0M
};
await wc.Product.Add(p);

//Update products with new values
await wc.Product.Update(16, new Product { name = "test 9" });

//Update products with Null values
await wc.Product.UpdateWithNull(16, new { name = "test 9", weight = "", date_on_sale_from = "", date_on_sale_to = "" });

//Delete product
await wc.Product.Delete(15);

//Use parameters
var products1 = await wc.Product.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "include", "10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15" },
                { "per_page", "15" } });
```

Comment: What does `Product` look like? I imagine there should be some sort of unique ID tied to it (hopefully it is not `name` as that member name doesn't indicate its an ID, but it looks like is being used as one).  Whatever the unique ID is, you should probably query for it first.  If you find it, do your updates, if not, create it.

Comment: Well name will be as "computer lenovo" or something else like it Id needs to be connected to the wares yes